# How to validate and scroll to sap.m.RadioButtonGroup

Tags: sapui5

The task is straight forward:
The user has to select an entry in a group of radio buttons, otherwise the validation should fail.
[image: RadioButtonGroup]
In order to be nice to the user, I'd also like to scroll to that RadioButtonGroup when its validation fails since it's further down and may not be in sight (as in my example linked below).

The implementation is not so straight forward to me because [RadioButtonGroup](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.RadioButtonGroup) does not have the property `required`.
[Here's my code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nVp28OjX6CvMMFEr?preview) - the RadioButtonGroup is in file `SomeView.view.xml` at line 420...
I have not really tried anything so far because I have no idea what to try.

Does anyone know if this is possible without compromising the existing validator implementation (that I got from [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/11/01/generic-sapui5-form-validator/))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The implementation is not so straight forward to me because RadioButtonGroup does not have the property required.

Only  `sap.m.Label` needs the property `required="true"`. Not the control `sap.m.RadioButtonGroup` itself.

The control `sap.m.RadioButtonGroup` has a property called `selectedIndex`. In your Code-Snippet you set the property `selectedIndex="-1"`. If the user selects an `sap.m.Radiobutton` the `selectedIndex` will change to 0..3. Let's capture that with  `sap.ui.model.type.Integer`.

```js
 // JSON dummy data
            var oData = {
                text   : "Test",
                userEmail : "i.am@groot.com",
                number : 50,
                date   : "01.01.2021",
                selectedIndex: -1
            };
```

```xml
 <Label text="Final answer?" required="true"/>
            <RadioButtonGroup 
               id="answer" 
               columns="4" 
               selectedIndex="{ path: '/selectedIndex',
               type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Integer',
               constraints : { 
                              minimum : 0, 
                              maximum : 3 
                             }}">
                <RadioButton id="A1" text="A"/>
                <RadioButton id="B1" text="B"/>
                <RadioButton id="C1" text="C"/>
                <RadioButton id="D1" text="D"/>
            </RadioButtonGroup>
```

The `Validator.js` only checks for following properties

```js
 aValidateProperties   = ["value", "selectedKey", "text"]
```

so we add the propertie `selectedIndex`

```js
aValidateProperties   = ["value", "selectedKey", "text", "selectedIndex"]
```

Validation works now ! [Code-Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mlGoPFv3cZMvIiIP)

> In order to be nice to the user, I'd also like to scroll to that RadioButtonGroup when its validation fails since it's further down and may not be in sight (as in my example linked below).

[See this offical Example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.MessagePopover/sample/sap.m.sample.MessagePopoverMessageHandling)

Comment: this is the best answer I've seen in a while, nicely explained and even with fully working examples, thank you so much! I didn't get it to work at first because I accidentally set  `selectedIndex` to a string in my json file - `"selectedIndex":"-1"` - but after correcting it it worked.